# Cannot import C++ header in Cocoapods umbrella header

Tags: c++, ios, swift, react-native, cocoapods

**Overview: the umbrella header for my pod imports a file that requires C++ - my pod fails at compile time on this umbrella header. I'm using React Native Turbo Modules, but I was wondering if this was an issue with Cocoapods.**

I've created a pod with Objective-C++ and Swift files, when I run `pod install`, it creates an umbrella header:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#else
#ifndef FOUNDATION_EXPORT
#if defined(__cplusplus)
#define FOUNDATION_EXPORT extern "C"
#else
#define FOUNDATION_EXPORT extern
#endif
#endif
#endif

#import "MyHeader.h"

FOUNDATION_EXPORT double my_framework_sdkVersionNumber;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char my_framework_sdkVersionString[];
```

`MyHeader.h` has an objective-c++ implementation file named `MyHeader.mm`. `MyHeader.h` imports `MySDKSpec.h` which includes this:

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
#error This file must be compiled as Obj-C++. If you are importing it, you must change your file extension to .mm.
#endif
```

When I try to build my Cocoapods project, it fails at compiling the umbrella header because it doesn't use C++. It shows this error (from `MySDKSpec.h`):

> This file must be compiled as Obj-C++. If you are importing it, you must change your file extension to .mm.

In my podspec I tried adding this but it still doesn't work:

```
  s.pod_target_xcconfig    = {
    "HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" => "\"$(PODS_ROOT)/boost\"",
    "OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS" => "-DFOLLY_NO_CONFIG -DFOLLY_MOBILE=1 -DFOLLY_USE_LIBCPP=1",
    "CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD" => "c++17",
    'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-l"stdc++"',
    'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/LibTorch/install/include"',
  }
```

If I remove `#import "MyHeader.h"` from the umbrella header, the app compiles fine. This is because I don't need to reference the Objective-C++ code from Swift, just use Swift in Objective-C++ (which works). But running `pod install` generates this umbrella header automatically.

Is there a way to force C++ for this umbrella header? Or can I make Cocoapods not create it automatically?

*I'm using React Native Turbo Modules which is relatively new, and it automatically creates the `MySDKSpec.h` file, as it requires C++.*

Comment: have you some solution?

Comment: Same here, it happens with React Native and gets solved by removing the `#import "FBReactNativeSpec.h"` from the umbrella header. It comes back again with pod install though.
Any updates?

Comment: for me, the issue was in package.json - the `name` in `codegenConfig` needs to be unique in the sense that it must differ from your old module name, because otherwise the codegen-generated headers can be confused with the original ones, and you can end up with this error.